# ng-if with JSON feed array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Quite simply if I use:

```
{{item.areas[0]["post-codes"]}}
```

I can render out the required value.

If however I do:

```
<li ng-if="{{item.areas[0]["post-codes"]}} == yes">
```

Angular complains - what's the best approach for values like these?

Comment: what's the value of item.areas[0]["post-codes"] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the value actually `yes`? Is it a string, or is it the boolean value `true`?

- You are also going to have a problem with your quotes there.
- There should be no need for the curly braces inside the `ng-if`.
- You should be using an identity operator (`===`)

Something like this:

```
<li ng-if="item.areas[0]['post-codes'] === 'yes'">
```

Comment: it is a string so not a boolean, the above worked great - thanks.